# Value in object returns to empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a select form with data retrieved from a JSON url. When I select something, I want the value to be put into `$scope.afspraak.groep`. For some reason, the value returns to the original value which is empty.

Here is my code:

```
<select id="selectgroep" name="selectgroep" class="form-control" size='5' ng-model="afspraak.groep" ng-options="t.id as t.id for t in objecten" ng-click="test()">


</select>

$scope.afspraak = {     
    groep: '',
};

$scope.passData = function(data) {
    $scope.afspraak.groep = data;
}

$scope.test = function() {
    console.log($scope.afspraak);
}
```

I have used various methods such as changing ng-click to passData(afspraak.groep), but it still doesn't work. The weird thing is that in another partial, I have the exact similar code and that does work shown here:

```
<select id="selectvak" name="selectvak" class="form-control" size='5' ng-model="user.vakid" ng-options="t.id as t.id for t in vak" ng-click="getKlas(user.vakid); test()">
</select>

$scope.user = {
vakid: '',
};

$scope.test = function() {
    console.log($scope.user);
}

$scope.getKlas = function (ID){
    afsprakenService.getKlassen(ID)
    .success(function (klas){
        $scope.klas = klas;
        $scope.alerts.push({ type: 'success', msg: 'Retrieved'});
    })
    .error(function (error) {
        $scope.alerts.push({ type: 'danger', msg: 'Error retrieving! ' + error.message});
    });
};
```

What am I doing wrong here? The only difference that I see is the method in the second select form which is getKlas where I pass the ng-model to use in another function.

Edit: this is now solved! It turns out that a label class is what was causing the deletion. I removed it by accident and it works now!

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/zqnsam4p/

Comment: @AlexSzabó Isn't that the same as my code?

Answer (score 0):

To set a models value from a select it is sufficient to have a `ng-model` on it. In case you want to do some extra action when selecting an option you should use `ng-change` and not `ng-click`.

A good way to debug your models, to check in real time if it was updated and view its values do something like this

```
<pre>{{ myModel | json }}</pre>
```

Here is a working fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jub58sem/2/

Comment: I have applied your piece of code to my page to show if `afspraak.groep` changes. It does in fact change, but as soon as I console log `afspraak.groep`, it shows that the value is empty again. Eventually I am going to send `afspraak` to the backend, so it can't be empty. How will I know the value will stay what I have chosen?

Edit: when I console.log `afspraak.groep`, the value in the <pre> stays the value that I have selected.

Comment: From the code you posted I cannot see any timer or action that would reset the value. Add a <pre> to your html and check the model values to check if you the data is there

Comment: That's because there is no timer of action that would reset the value and that's why I am so confused about it. Logging `afspraak` would show me all the values that are in that object, but it's showing it as empty.

Comment: Can't see your whole code, but are you under the controllers scope?

Comment: Yes. My test() is in my controller, so I know I'm using the right controller.